# Obtaining HITIds with a specific HITTypeId using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, mechanicalturk

I'm using aws cli to obtain a table that contains HITId of only one particular HITTypeId.

Query:

```
aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[].{"1. HITId": HITId, "2. Title": Title, "3. Status":HITStatus, "4. HITTypeID": HITTypeId}' --hit-type-id "ABCD" --endpoint-url https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --max-results 100
```

Output:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: --hit-type-id, ABCD
```

Bit new to AWS CLI, How to tackle this?

Also, I tried with:

```
aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[?HITTypeId='ABCD'].{"1. HITId": HITId, "2. Title": Title, "3. Status":HITStatus, "4. HITTypeID": HITTypeId}' --endpoint-url https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --max-results 100
```

Which certainly gave me a syntax error (Was trying to relate it to Querying on table).

Reference: https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-managing-mturk-hits-with-the-aws-command-line-interface-56eaabb7fd4c

Comment: Could you give more details on the syntax error you received?

Comment: The error posted is all it printed. Your method worked (The modification to my 2nd query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your filter query. The [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter) uses [JMESPath Specification](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#filter-expressions) which uses `==` for equality, you are using `?HITTypeId='ABCD'`

Try the following command:

```
aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[?HITTypeId==`ABCD`].{"1. HITId": HITId, "2. Title": Title, "3. Status":HITStatus, "4. HITTypeID": HITTypeId}' --endpoint-url https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --max-results 100
```

Comment: Thanks for documentation and references, that worked. Just a minor change, ```aws mturk list-hits --output table --query 'HITs[?HITTypeId==`ABCD`]```  we'll need to enclose ABCD in back tics (``) rather than single inverted commas ('')

Comment: Updated the answer to use the back tics, thanks for following up with that :)